Duplicating firestore databases in different regions
How can I copy data from one firestore database to another in the same project but different regions?
I want to move my app's data to a new region that is closer to my location.
I have tried exporting the data from the firestore in the european region to and importing it to the new firestore in johannesburg, but I can't due to the different regions.

Please edit the question to explain in more detail what didn't work the way you expected with whatever you tried.  We should be able to take your instructions and duplicate the results.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.
